# how to create the object processInstance in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, approval-process

how to create the object processInstance in test class?

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing:
>   [ProcessDefinitionId, CurrentNodeId]: [ProcessDefinitionId,
>   CurrentNodeId]

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this [Apex Approval Processing Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_process_example.htm).

You should use the `Approval.Process` method ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_approval.htm)).

```
public class ApprovalExample {
    void submitAndProcessApprovalRequest() {
        // Insert an account
        Account a = new Account(Name='Example');
        insert a;

        User user1 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Alias='example'];

        // Create an approval request for the account
        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = 
            new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        req1.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
        req1.setObjectId(a.id);

        // Submit on behalf of a specific submitter
        req1.setSubmitterId(user1.Id); 

        // Submit the record to specific process and skip the criteria evaluation
        req1.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId('Example_Process');
        req1.setSkipEntryCriteria(true);

        // Submit the approval request for the account
        Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);

        // Now you have a ProcessInstance record
}
```